# get last occuerrence of a line with 2 specific words in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have a text file ( basically a log file) in linux and i have 2 words (alpha, beta).

Now i trying to to search these two words in one line and then print that line and next 15 lines in a temp file. there would be many lines with alpha and beta But I need only last occurrence with "alpha" and "beta" and next 15 lines.

I'll be thankful if you also tell me command in case number of words increase, like 3 or 4 word to search on same line, alpha, beta, gamma

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your wording was a bit ambiguous, did you want a line with both alpha AND beta or alpha OR beta.  If the first:

```
grep -EA15 'alpha.*beta|beta.*alpha' | tail -16
```

if the second:

```
grep -wA15 'alpha|beta' | tail -16
```

Comment: I think it should be `tail -16`, or the match itself won't be displayed.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity: Depending on the shell, you may want to escape '|' with '\|' if you forget '-E'. So, it would be `grep -wA15 'alpha\|beta' | tail -16` or `grep -wEA15 'alpha|beta' | tail -16`.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity:Kindly tell me where should i place filename? as i dont see filename variable in above given syntax.

Comment: either piped into stdin, or before the `| tail`

Answer (score 1):

OmnipotentEntity's is definitely the way to go as long as you stick to 2 words per line.  However, it doesn't really scale well beyond that because of the combinatorial explosion in the regex.  If you need to match 4 or 5 words in a line, I think something like the below will work without adjustment (i have only tested this partially):

```
#!/bin/bash 

context=15
file=$1
shift

cmd="cat -n $file"
for s in $@
do
   cmd="$cmd | grep $s"
done

begin=$(eval $cmd | tail -1 | cut -f1)
(( end=$begin + $context ))

sed -n $begin,${end}p $file
```

The idea is that we attach line numbers to the input file and then build up a series of grep filters. We extract the line number of the last line that passes all the filters and use sed to print out the required range.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/alpha.*beta\|beta.*alpha/,+15{//{h;d};H};$!d;g;/^$/d' file
```

or this (all sed's):

```
sed '/alpha.*beta\|beta.*alpha/{:a;$bb;N;s/\n/&/15;tb;ba;:b;$q;x};$!d;g;/^$/d' file
```

With two words the regexp `/alpha.*beta\|beta.*alpha/` is acceptable, but from there on it gets more tricky to remember all the different combinations. A better way is to list the words as separate regexps at any point bailing out if the line does not contain the current regexp:

```
sed '/alpha/!bc;/beta/!bc;/gamma/!bc;/delta/!bc;:a;$bb;N;s/\n/&/15;tb;ba;:b;$q;x;d;:c;$!d;g;/^$/d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

See the following code :

```
awk '
    {
        file[NR]=$0
    }
    END{
        for (i=NR; i>0; i--) {
            if (file[i] ~ /^alpha, beta/)  {
                for (j=i; j<=i+15; j++) {
                    print file[j]
                }
                exit
            }
        }
    }
' FILE
```

The algorithm is :

- for each lines of the file, we feed and array with the current line number as key
- at the end of the file, we search for the first occurrence of "alpha, beta" in **reversed order**
- when the line match, we print this and go in ASC orderto print each values while the array key can be incremented 15 times

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed too:

```
sed -n '/alpha.*beta|beta.*alpha/,+15p' file | tail -n 16
```

Comment: I think you might need to backslash the alternation i.e. `\|`

Answer (score -2):

to get the last occurrence of a specific word: "tail"

```
grep myword myfile.txt| tail -1
```

For multiple words,

```
grep -w 'word1|word2' myfile.txt| tail -1
```

For the last 15 instances of either word,

```
grep -w 'word1|word2' myfile.txt| tail -15
```

for more complex scenarios: "sed" or "awk".

Comment: It's not last 15 instances. It's the last instance and 15 trailing lines.